# Python regex: XOR operator

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose I have strings like these:

1. `"DT NN IN NN"`
2. `"DT RB JJ NN"`
3. `"DT JJ JJ NN"`
4. `"DT RB RB NN NN"`
5. `"DT RB RB"`

So, I have a list of strings:

```
list = ["DT NN IN NN", "DT RB JJ NN", "DT JJ JJ NN", "DT RB RB NN NN", "DT RB RB"]
```

I have the following code:

```
pattern = "(?:DT\s+)+([?:RB\s+|?:JJ\s+])+(?:NN\s+)*NN$"
for item in list:
    m = re.match(pattern, item)
    if m:
        print item
```

What I want from `pattern` is to match the strings that start with `DT` (appears one or more times) have either `RB` or `JJ` (appearing once or more), but not both, and then to end with `NN` (again, appearing once or more).

So, in the final result I should get 3 and 4 printed on the screen. However, with my regex, in addition I get 2, which I don't want. How do I change `pattern` so this could work? How to replace the pipe (OR) with a XOR?

Comment: So `NN` can be repeated an arbitrary amount of times?

Comment: In this case a it would be much simpler not to use regex.

Comment: Yes, `NN` can be repeated multiple times, but it must end with at least one `NN`.

Comment: @Belphegor: can `NN` be interleaved with for instance `JJ`? Is `DT JJ NN JJ NN` a valid string?

Comment: @Belphegor: doing natural language pattern processing using regexes? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you define the presence of `RB` and `JJ`. You haven't mentioned that only either of them should be present. This can be achieved by separating them with a `|` (pipe) and letting either of them repeat one or more times (`+`). Try changing your pattern to this:

```
pattern = "(?:DT\s+)+(?:(RB\s+)+|(JJ\s+)+)(?:NN\s+)*NN$"
```

Besides, `(?:<something>)` is called a non-capturing group. You use it to say "I want `<something>` to be matched, but not included when I select groups later. And by the looks of it, you are not using any groups. You are simply printing the whole `item` (unless you've masked the code for brevity). If you actually do not need groups, here is a simple version that would work for you:

```
pattern = "(DT\s+)+((RB\s+)+|(JJ\s+)+)(NN\s*)*NN$"
```

I have also let the ending set of white spaces occur 0 or more times, instead of one or more times like you original pattern. Feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` is a *character class*, you are matching a set of characters that include `?`, `:` and `+` and `|`, among others. Other than `-` to mark a series, there are no modifiers or special characters in a character class.

You need to match either a repetition of `RB`, or of `JJ`:

```
pattern = r"(?:DT\s+)+(?:(?:RB\s+)+|(?:JJ\s+)+)NN"
```

I've simplified this down; you are not using any of the groups anyway.

Online demo for this pattern: https://regex101.com/r/iH4lE6/1

Since you are not relying on capturing groups, so there is not really any point in using non-capturing groups either; just use `(...)` instead of `(?:...)` for a less verbose regex.

You may want to add anchors to make sure `DT` only matches at the start, and replace the `NN` at the end with `(NN\s+)*NN$` to anchor it at the end, and move the whitespace matching to the start of each repeated group:

```
pattern = r"^DT(\s+DT)*((\s+RB)+|(\s+JJ)+)(\s+NN)+$"
```

Online demo for this version: https://regex101.com/r/iH4lE6/2

Comment: Based on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898679/python-regex-xor-operator/37898783#comment63250527_37898679) `NN` can be repeated an arbitrary amount of times.

Comment: This is not working for me, I get a match on a pattern like "DT JJ JJ NN JJ NN DT NN", and I don't need that. It must start with DT, have at least one (or more) RB or JJ, and then end with one or more NN.

Comment: @Belphegor: updated; can you update your question to include that sample?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, now this works (with one exception: DT can appear more than once, I updated the question). Anyway, another answer was quicker, so I accepted that one. Thanks for the help +1!

Comment: @Belphegor: right, updated to match repeated DTs at the start then!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can solve this problem by first splitting it into two separate problems:

- A regex that starts with `DT` followed by one or more `RB`s followed by one or more `NN`s:

  ```
  ^DT(\s+DT)*(\s+RB)+(\s+NN)+$
  ```
- A regex that starts with `DT` followed by one or more `JJ`s followed by one or more `NN`s:

  ```
  ^DT(\s+DT)*(\s+JJ)+(\s+NN)+$
  ```

Now you can simply put a pipe (or operator) between these two:

```
^((DT(\s+DT)*(\s+RB)+(\s+NN)+)|(DT(\s+DT)*(\s+JJ)+(\s+NN)+))$
```

and later simplify it by refactoring it to:

```
^DT(\s+DT)*((\s+RB)+|(\s+JJ)+)(\s+NN)+$
```

Or a visual representation using [Regexper](https://regexper.com):

[image: visual representation of the regex]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this works with one exception: DT can appear once or more times (I just saw that I forgot to mention that in my original question). I accepted another answer, because this works there + the other guy was faster :) +1 for your detailed answer, it definitely helps!