# Reg Exp don't select if more than one group matches (multiple XOR)

Tags: regex, oracle12c, regex-group

The data are held in an Oracle 12c database, one row per ICD-10-CM code, with a patient ID (foreign key) like so (note that there could be many other codes, the following are just the ones pertinent to this question):

```
ID   ICD10CODE
 1   S72.91XB
 1   S72.92XB
 2   S72.211A
 3   S72.414A
 3   S72.415A
 4   S32.509A
 5   S32.301A
 5   S32.821A
 6   S32.421A
 6   S32.422A
 7   S32.421A
 8   S32.421A
 8   S32.509A
```

The task at hand is to select distinct patients that match **only one** of the following points (using standard regular expression syntax):

- Any number of: `S32\.1\w\w\w`, `S32\.2\w\w\w`, `S32\.3\w\w\w`, `S32\.5\w\w\w`, `S32\.6\w\w\w`, `S32\.7\w\w\w`, `S32\.8\w\w\w`
- Any number of: `S32\.4\w1\w`, `S32\.4\w3\w`, `S32\.4\w4\w`, `S32\.4\w6\w`, `S32\.4\w7\w`, `S32\.4\w8\w`, `S32\.4\w9\w`
- Any number of: `S32\.4\w2\w`, `S32\.4\w3\w`, `S32\.4\w5\w`, `S32\.4\w6\w`, `S32\.4\w7\w`, `S32\.4\w8\w`, `S32\.4\w9\w`
- Any number of: `S72\.[0-8]\w1\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w3\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w4\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w6\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w7\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w8\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w9\w`
- Any number of: `S72\.[0-8]\w2\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w3\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w5\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w6\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w7\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w8\w`, `S72\.[0-8]\w9\w`
- Any number of: `S72\.91\w\w`, `S72\.93\w\w`, `S72\.94\w\w`, `S72\.96\w\w`, `S72\.97\w\w`, `S72\.98\w\w`, `S72\.99\w\w`
- Any number of: `S72\.92\w\w`, `S72\.93\w\w`, `S72\.95\w\w`, `S72\.96\w\w`, `S72\.97\w\w`, `S72\.98\w\w`, `S72\.99\w\w`

Any permutation or combination (including repetitions) of codes listed within a bullet are permitted for each patient, but permutations or combinations across rows should occur mutually exclusively for a patient. My method is to apply `LISTAGG` on `GROUP BY ID`:

```
ID  LISTAGG(ICD10CODE, ',')
 1  S72.91XB,S72.92XB
 2  S72.211A
 3  S72.414A,S72.415A
 4  S32.509A
 5  S32.301A,S32.821A
 6  S32.421A,S32.422A
 7  S32.421A
 8  S32.421A,S32.509A
```

Then filter using this regular expression, `(S32\.(([1-3]|[5-8])|(4\w((1|4)|(2|5)|(3)|([5-9]))))\w+)|(S72\.(([0-8]\w((1|4)|(2|5)|(3)|([5-9])))|(9((1|4)|(2|5)|(3)|([5-9]))))\w+)`, which is almost a literal representation of the bullets above. My expression is adapted from the idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898762/3765319), where it seems that, `((RB\s+)+|(JJ\s+)+)` automatically selects either `"RB"` or `"JJ"`, but not both.

I cannot get it to work. The answer should contain only IDs 2, 4, 5, and 7. But, the expression I developed matches all IDs.

What is a solution to this problem?

---

[Edit] Some more information:

All these S codes above relate to injuries to the bones in the lower extremity: `S32` is for fractures of the pelvis (hip bone), `S72` is for fractures of the femur (thigh bone). Note that we have two femurs, and two acetabulum (socket of the pelvis where the femur connects). The `S32.4` code denotes the acetabulum (the rest of the `S32.[1235678]\w{3}` series denotes other parts of the pelvis). Right and left femur and acetabulum are denoted by `1|4` or `2|5` in the 6th character, respectively, unless the code starts with `S72.9` when those numbers appear in the 5th character.

*The patients to be included in the study population should only have one of the bones broken.* That means, one of the two femurs, one of the acetabulum, or the pelvis, but not a combination of them. Combinations of fractures of a single bone do not matter. For example, the right single femur can be broken in 10 different places and ways (the knee area, the middle shaft, the head, etc., each generating a different `S72.\w[1|4]\w{2}` code), and should still be selected.

Comment: `S32\.4\w[36789]\w` matches are in both the 2nd and 3rd bullet points. Any `id` that contains that match cannot be mutually exclusive to a single group.

Comment: So is it true that each bullet is exclusive. And an ID can contain only a single bullrt's permutation ?

Comment: What did you want to do with the cells that don't match ? `^(?:(?:S32\.[1-35-8]\w\w\w,?)+|(?:S32\.4\w[1346-9]\w,?)+|(?:S32\.4\w[235-9]\w,?)+|(?:S72\.[0-8]\w[1346-9]\w,?)+|(?:S72\.[0-8]\w[235-9]\w,?)+|(?:S72\.9[1346-9]\w\w,?)+|(?:S72\.9[235-9]\w\w,?)+)$`

https://regex101.com/r/becVjP/1 This is run through refactor software.

Comment: The S32's and S72's can't be factored further because it would result in the bullet boundary's being crossed. Also, you could convert the group notation from `(?: )` to `( )`

Comment: @sln Oracle does not support non-capturing `(?:)` groups so it would not be a "you could", you would need to.

Comment: @MT0 - `^((S32\.[1-35-8]\w\w\w,?)+|(S32\.4\w[1346-9]\w,?)+|(S32\.4\w[235-9]\w,?)+|(S72\.[0-8]\w[1346-9]\w,?)+|(S72\.[0-8]\w[235-9]\w,?)+|(S72\.9[1346-9]\w\w,?)+|(S72\.9[235-9]\w\w,?)+)$`

Comment: @sln `(,|$)` seems a better terminator for each `icd10code` match than `,?` as it forces there to always be a comma between each item.

Comment: @MT0 - Not really.  You could make the argument that the delimiter is `,` and always there, thus `,?`. Or you could make the argument that `(,|$)` is both the delimiter and terminator, but it can't be both as `XX0123,XX456,`PP098 would match, i.e there is no termination at all.

Comment: @sin However, your expression would match `S32.421AS32.421A` when it should not be matched.

Comment: @MT0 - Yes it would. That's why the argument `that the delimiter is , and always there` is more usable. It's easily fixed with an `XXX\w(,XXX\w)*` but that can be done. However it's unlikely a generated field data would error and forget to inject a comma.

Comment: @MTO, yeah, you're right. @sln also, `[14]` & `[25]` are exclusive. The idea is, `S32\.[1-35-8]` refer to the whole pelvis bone ring, except for the sockets where legs fit, which is `S32\.4`. `S72` refers to the thigh bone. We have 2 thigh bones, 2 sockets where they fit, and 1 pelvis. I need cases where 1 thigh or 1 socket or the pelvis is exclusively broken, no combinations. `[14]` in 6th digit indicates left, `[25]` right, except for `S72.9`, where it is the 5th digit. 6th digit `3` indicates unspecified, `5-9` are other complications. Those don't matter (in combination ok).

Comment: I'm lost @Kartik you should update that in your question. Regex doesn't know about bones really. The regex in my comment originate from your bullet info and are correct to that.

Comment: Lol, and I tried to simply things. Basically, only one bone needs to be broken, either a thigh, or the socket where they fit, or the pelvic girdle. The codes are whacky, since body is a complex machine. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @MT0 - You could always do `(,(?!$)|$)` but I'm assuming Oracle won't do assertions like that.

Comment: @Kartik - Be aware that the regex is a compound expression with per bullet exclusive group sections that don't intersect. But anything is possible, update the question with further details.

Comment: So, it seems like the expression I had and the ones you have differ mainly in the `,?` or `,|$`. What do they do, exactly? Obviously yours are also more compact and there could be other differences too, but I don't think they are as major as the terminators. Correct?

Comment: @sln, added the additional info to the question.

Comment: Just thinking, does it not make it easier if the expression is flipped around? So exclude lines where pelvis and femur, or pelvis and acetabulum, or femur and acetabulum, or left and right femur or left and right acetabulum exist. That will only be 5 things to check, right?

Comment: @Kartik If you ever get the situation where you have a code that is `XYZ` and a code that is `XYZXYZ` then using `^(XYZ,?)+$` would match both the `XYZ` and `XYZXYZ` codes as the comma is optional; however `^(XYZ(,|$))+$` would only match `XYZ` and never match `XYZXYZ` as the comma between codes can only ever not be present when the end-of-the-string has been reached and there will be no more codes, which appears to be the desired behaviour. You may not ever have that situation but there is a difference where `,?` can generate false-positives that `(,|$)` would never generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:

You can do it with a single regular expression:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       t.icd10codes
FROM   ( SELECT id,
                LISTAGG(icd10code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY icd10code)
                  AS icd10codes
         FROM   table_name
         GROUP BY id
       ) t
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         t.icd10codes,
             '^(S32\.[1235678]\w\w\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S32\.4\w[1346789]\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S32\.4\w[2356789]\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S72\.[0-8]\w[1346789]\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S72\.[0-8]\w[2356789]\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S72\.9[1346789]\w\w(,|$))+$'
         || '|^(S72\.9[2356789]\w\w(,|$))+$'
       )
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, ICD10CODE) AS
SELECT 1, 'S72.91XB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S72.92XB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S72.211A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S72.414A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S72.415A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S32.509A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S32.301A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S32.821A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S32.421A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S32.422A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S32.421A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'S32.421A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'S32.509A' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ICD10CODES |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | S72.211A |
> | 4 | S32.509A |
> | 5 | S32.301A,S32.821A |
> | 7 | S32.421A |

---

#### Option 2:

You can put the regular expressions into a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE matches (id, match) AS
SELECT 1, 'S32\.[1235678]\w\w\w'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32\.4\w[1346789]\w'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32\.4\w[2356789]\w'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72\.[0-8]\w[1346789]\w' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72\.[0-8]\w[2356789]\w' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72\.9[1346789]\w\w'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72\.9[2356789]\w\w'     FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use the query:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       m.id AS match_id,
       LISTAGG(t.icd10code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.icd10code)
         AS icd10codes
FROM   table_name t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN matches m
       PARTITION BY (m.id)
       ON (REGEXP_LIKE(t.icd10code, '^' || m.match || '$'))
GROUP BY
       t.id,
       m.id
HAVING
       COUNT(m.match) = COUNT(t.id);
```

#### Option 3:

Similar to the first option, but you can put the matches into a table and you can determine which match has been used:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       m.id AS match_id,
       t.icd10codes
FROM   ( SELECT id,
                LISTAGG(icd10code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY icd10code)
                  AS icd10codes
         FROM   table_name
         GROUP BY id
       ) t
       INNER JOIN matches m
       ON (REGEXP_LIKE(t.icd10codes, '^(' || m.match || '(,|$))+$' ))
```

Options 2 & 3 both output:

> | ID | MATCH_ID | ICD10CODES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | 1 | S32.509A |
> | 5 | 1 | S32.301A,S32.821A |
> | 7 | 2 | S32.421A |
> | 2 | 4 | S72.211A |

---

#### Option 4:

You can also get rid of the (slow) regular expressions and use `LIKE` if you store the matches as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE matches (id, match) AS
SELECT 1, 'S32.1___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.2___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.3___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.5___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.6___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.7___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S32.8___' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_1_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_3_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_4_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_6_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_7_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_8_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'S32.4_9_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_2_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_3_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_5_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_6_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_7_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_8_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'S32.4_9_' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_1_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_3_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_4_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_6_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_7_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_8_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_9_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_2_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_3_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_5_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_6_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_7_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_8_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'S72.' || (LEVEL - 1) || '_9_' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.91__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.93__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.94__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.96__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.97__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.98__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'S72.99__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.92__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.93__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.95__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.96__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.97__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.98__' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'S72.99__' FROM DUAL;
```

Then use the query:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       m.id AS match_id,
       LISTAGG(t.icd10code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.icd10code)
         AS icd10codes
FROM   table_name t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN matches m
       PARTITION BY (m.id)
       ON (t.icd10code LIKE m.match)
GROUP BY
       t.id,
       m.id
HAVING
       COUNT(m.match) = COUNT(t.id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1093b65e1aaa9b4cccc220ca11880cac)*

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I will try them out and let you know.

Comment: So, answer is fully exclusive to `S32` and `S72` codes, which is great. But, often such fractures present with injuries to other parts, usually minor (it takes a lot to break a pelvis and femur). The solution effectively excludes them all. Can we do something to fix it, like `SELECT 1` when `'S32\.[1235678]\w\w\w'` exists, `1` when `'S32\.4\w[1346789]\w'` exists, etc., take sum, exclude records with counts greater than 1? I think small change to Option 2 or 3 will do it. Option 4 is great, but not extendable. I get a lot of such queries, usually not as complex.

Comment: @Kartik See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1bd43e0fcaad757bae128ed79330e89c) - it shows how to extend all four options to change from matching `S32\.[1235678]\w\w\w` to matching `(S32\.[1235678]\w\w\w|S32\.4\w[1346789]\w)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've added your broken bones codes to the S32 and S72 series.
That's all that needed to be done really.

Feel free to change `,?` to `(,|$)` but don't change anything else.
Let me know if the broken bones codes is about right.

- `S32\.\w[25]\w\w`, S32.1\w\w\w, S32.2\w\w\w, S32.3\w\w\w, S32.5\w\w\w, S32.6\w\w\w, S32.7\w\w\w, S32.8\w\w\w
- `S32\.\w[25]\w\w`, S32.4\w1\w, S32.4\w3\w, S32.4\w4\w, S32.4\w6\w, S32.4\w7\w, S32.4\w8\w, S32.4\w9\w
- `S32\.\w[25]\w\w`, S32.4\w2\w, S32.4\w3\w, S32.4\w5\w, S32.4\w6\w, S32.4\w7\w, S32.4\w8\w, S32.4\w9\w
- `S72\.\w[14]\w\w`, S72.[0-8]\w1\w, S72.[0-8]\w3\w, S72.[0-8]\w4\w, S72.[0-8]\w6\w, S72.[0-8]\w7\w, S72.[0-8]\w8\w, S72.[0-8]\w9\w
- `S72\.\w[14]\w\w`, S72.[0-8]\w2\w, S72.[0-8]\w3\w, S72.[0-8]\w5\w, S72.[0-8]\w6\w, S72.[0-8]\w7\w, S72.[0-8]\w8\w, S72.[0-8]\w9\w
- `S72\.[14]\w\w\w`, S72.91\w\w, S72.93\w\w, S72.94\w\w, S72.96\w\w, S72.97\w\w, S72.98\w\w, S72.99\w\w
- `S72\.[14]\w\w\w`, S72.92\w\w, S72.93\w\w, S72.95\w\w, S72.96\w\w, S72.97\w\w, S72.98\w\w, S72.99\w\w

The new regex is

```
^((S32\.(\w[25]|[1-35-8]\w)\w\w,?)+|(S32\.(\w[25]\w|4\w[1346-9])\w,?)+|(S32\.(\w[25]\w|4\w[235-9])\w,?)+|(S72\.(\w[14]\w|[0-8]\w[1346-9])\w,?)+|(S72\.(\w[14]\w|[0-8]\w[235-9])\w,?)+|(S72\.([14]\w|9[1346-9])\w\w,?)+|(S72\.([14]\w|9[235-9])\w\w,?)+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/OAHdCO/1

```
 ^ 
 (
    ( S32 \. ( \w [25] | [1-35-8] \w ) \w\w ,? )+
  | ( S32 \. ( \w [25] \w | 4 \w [1346-9] ) \w ,? )+
  | ( S32 \. ( \w [25] \w | 4 \w [235-9] ) \w ,? )+
  | ( S72 \. ( \w [14] \w | [0-8] \w [1346-9] ) \w ,? )+
  | ( S72 \. ( \w [14] \w | [0-8] \w [235-9] ) \w ,? )+
  | ( S72 \. ( [14] \w | 9 [1346-9] ) \w\w ,? )+
  | ( S72 \. ( [14] \w | 9 [235-9] ) \w\w ,? )+
 )
 $
```